# Error when trying to run cvs through Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, windows-7, cvs, runtime.exec, wincvs

I usually use WinCVS, but I'm trying to write a Java app to automate some of the build/deployment tasks. If I run `cvs -n update` from the command line, I get the results of the query. If I run it via Runtime.exec() I get the below error. Any ideas? Running on a Windows 7 machine.

```
cvs update: warning: unrecognized response 'error: Failed to create SSH connection server' from cvs server
cvs update: warning: unrecognized response 'error: Error (0x80090006): Invalid Signature.' from cvs server
cvs [update aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you should use `maven` or `ant` for this sort of thing. Of course rolling your own can be fun as a learning exercise but in a professional environment 99% of the time it's best to stick to standard build tools.

Comment: I agree with biziclop on the "standard tools". But, show your code that generates the error.